# How do I sort the results of this Python program from lowest to highest values?

Tags: python, sorting

Below is my code, which generates X instances of random numbers between 0 and 101.

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Enter desired number: "))

def randoTaker():
    print(random.randint(0, 101))

randoTaker()

for i in range(x-1):
    randoTaker()
```

My question: how do I sort these results from low to high? For example: let's say my current output for an input of value of 4 is 12, 34, 5, 45. My desired result would be 5, 12, 34, 45.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Have you searched [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Comment: Do you want to sort after printing them unsorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the below;

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Enter desired number: "))

def randoTaker():
    return random.randint(0, 101)

for j in sorted([randoTaker() for i in range(x)]):
    print j
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing your results rather than storing them.  You probably want to save them in a list, then sort the list:

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Enter desired number: "))

def randoTaker():
    return random.randint(0, 101)

results = []
for i in range(x-1):
    results.append(randoTaker())

results.sort()

print results
```

If you really want, you can use a list comprehension:

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Enter desired number: "))

def randoTaker():
    return random.randint(0, 101)

print sorted([randoTaker() for i in range(x-1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are just printing the value inside your function. If you want to sort the random numbers generated, you should consider returning the numbers and then adding them to a list.

Once you have added all the numbers to a list, you can then use `list.sort()` function or `sorted()` function to sort the list.

Example:

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Enter desired number: "))

def randoTaker():
    return random.randint(0, 101)

print(randoTaker())

randlst = []
for i in range(x-1):
    randlst.append(randoTaker())

randlst.sort()
print(randlst)
```